# Javascript days of the week

Tags: javascript, html

The html that I am trying to write is `<iframe src="WEEKDAY.htm"></iframe>` Where the variable would be a WEEKDAY.

I have .htm files that are made for each day of the week and so the javascript function is supposed to read the day of the week and then from that I load the appropriate .htm.  I can't figure out how to do this, please help me..

Here is the Javascript function code:

```
function weekDay(){
   thisDate = new Date();
   var thisWDay=thisDate.getDay();
   var wdName = new Array("sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
       "thursday", "friday", "saturday");
   return wdName[thisWDay];
}
```

And here is what I have tried in my HTML page: (tried using the var wdName??)

```
<script>
weekDay();
document.write(thisDate);
document.write("<iframe 
src='wdName.htm'></iframe>")
</script>
```

Comment: You won't get much sympathy here.  You'd be much better off with a good, descriptive title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Should have not stayed for that extra drink

Comment: You'd better off learning some javascript basics than posing this specific question. In particular, learn how to concatenate strings.

Comment: Why not just set it out statically? Even if you must script it, that's still probably the way to start (then use javascript to control visibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `weekDay()` function will return the current day of the week, but your other code calls `weekDay()` and *doesn't do anything with its return value.*

You need to use the value together with some string concatenation:

```
var today = weekDay();
document.write("<iframe src='" + today + "'.htm'></iframe>");
```

Or just:

```
document.write("<iframe src='" + weekDay() + "'.htm'></iframe>");
```

> *"And here is what I have tried in my HTML page: (tried using the var wdName??)"*

You can't use `wdName` from outside the function, because it is a local variable accessible only inside the function. As it should be, given that (as explained above) the function returns the string you want. Note that your variable `thisDate` will be global because it is not declared with `var`. It is best practice to declare all variables with `var`, which in your case would make `thisDate` a local variable in that function. Also it is considered best practice to declare arrays with `[]` rather than `new Array()`, so:

```
function weekDay(){
   var thisDate = new Date();
   var thisWDay=thisDate.getDay();
   var wdName = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
       "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];
   return wdName[thisWDay];
}
```

Which simplifies to:

```
function weekDay(){
   return ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
       "thursday", "friday", "saturday"][ (new Date()).getDay() ];
}
```

Comment: You get a -1 because it is a homework problem. do you want people in your company that got their qualification from nicking others works?

Comment: Thanks so much for the informative post, its working now!

Comment: @user3502609: Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, and thus marking your question as "solved".

Comment: @EdHeal - It's not "nicking others' works" to ask for help, especially given that in this case the OP showed that they'd made an attempt that was halfway there - unless of course the OP went on to pretend like they'd come up with the final solution on their own. I want people in my company that aren't afraid to ask for help when they need it.

Comment: @nnnnnnn - the original question did not have any code